# Fiware - Configure AuthZForce with PEP Proxy

Tags: authentication, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wilma, authzforce

I deployed [Orion, Cygnus, Keyrock and PEP proxy](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware/tree/master/Fiware) using docker compose as you can see on the repository. But the security level implemented is not the desired.

```
keystone_url = "http://localhost:5000"
keyrock_url  = "http://localhost:8000"
orion        = "http://localhost"

def test_authzforce(create=0,usuario="idm",nombre="",password="idm",correo=""):
    if(create != 0):
        ktoken=get_token(keystone_url)
        create_user(keystone_url, ktoken,usuario,nombre,password,correo)
    token = get_access_token(keyrock_url,usuario,password)
    entities = get_all_entities(orion,token)
    print("""
    user:\t\t{}
    token:\t\t{}
    result:\t\t{}
    """.format(usuario,token,entities))

test_authzforce()
test_authzforce(1,"test1","test1","test1","tes1t@test.com")
```

using this [Python package](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware/blob/master/fiware.py), in the first call of the function, it uses the admin user to get the token, getting all the entities on Orion later. But in the second call the functions creates a new user without any authorization in the keyrock application and despite this can get the entities.

```
user:       idm
token:      ggeWahMo3x7gV7IAkg3hzzoRshEd6Y
result:     []


user:       test1
token:      zDTCiE7GkEFujQSGRjYs76SqL6hkad
result:     []

[Finished in 2.1s]
```

Then, trying to implement [Authzforce on this docker compose file](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware/blob/master/testing/docker-compose.yml), got these results, without giving access permissions to the same administrator:

```
user:       idm
token:      DZKTmiV289FPclWKwceiTi7JhvuIUq
result:     User token not authorized


user:       test1
token:      nPH8fdLQeDdJg6Bi1riJfRYybqITud
result:     User token not authorized

[Finished in 2.0s]
```

And this error on console

[image: and this error on console]

here you have all my authzforce configurations:

[Local_Settings GE Access control](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware/blob/master/testing/config/idm/local_settings.py#L631)

[Pep proxy configuration](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware/blob/master/testing/config/pepproxy/config.js#L36)

[azj.js cast recomended on the issue on link 8](https://github.com/RiosQ/IFiware/blob/master/testing/config/pepproxy/azf.js#L231)

[Issue 36 pep proxy (error persist)](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/issues/36)

Comment: Have you created the access rule at keyrock interface?

Comment: Dalton, what do you mean with the keyrock access rule? I dont find documentation about it, i only deployed authzforce but no added any other configuration to the  pep proxy or the keyrock normal configuration.

Comment: This issue 36 on pep proxy needs to be fixed definitely. Else the pep wrongly interprets Permit response from AuthzForce... as Deny :-( To confirm that, you may enable debug logs in the PEP proxy by changing `log_config.json`:
{
  "appenders": [
    { 
      "type": "console",
      "layout": {
        "type": "pattern",
        "pattern": "%d  - %p: %c - %m",
        "replaceConsole": true
      } 
    }
  ],
  "levels": {
    "Server": "DEBUG",
    "Root": "DEBUG",
    "HTTP-Client": "DEBUG",
    "AZF-Client": "DEBUG",
    "IDM-Client": "DEBUG",
    "Test": "DEBUG"
  }
}

Comment: Sevastián, you can see something related to [access rules here](https://keyrock.docs.apiary.io/#reference/keyrock-api/permissions/create-a-permission). I do not know where is the old documentation of Keyrock, but I remember that there was a tutorial related to this creation in the Keyrock interface (horizon). You can find something in this [user guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Identity_Management_-_KeyRock_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Get_applications_from_actor_.28user_or_organization.29). I hope these links help you.